# Can we efficiently factor $n$ given that $n=pq$ where $p,q$ are primes satisfying $p=a^2+b^2, q=2ab+1$ for some $a,b$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, factorization, symmetric-polynomials

Suppose we're given a particular number $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

We're also given that $n=pq$ where $p,q$ are unknown primes satisfying 
$$
p=a^2+b^2
$$ and 
$$
q=2ab+1
$$
for some $a,b$.

Is there an efficient way to factor $n$ given this extra information?

(This is motivated by [a question from the cryptography stack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/59921/rsa-factorization-for-special-primes-p-and-q/59962).)

Comment: At very least, a solution will imply a factorization of $n$. So, short answer is No.

Comment: A solution implies a factorization of $n$ when $n$ has the given form. Isn't it possible that the RHS could be leveraged to find a solution?

Comment: So, do you ask if factorization of integers in this form can be found faster than in general case? I would then first ask if one can identify if $n$ has the given form without knowing/finding $a,b$.

Comment: According to the referenced crypto question, it's given that $n$ has this form but $a,b$ are unknown. Sorry, I edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: The original question suggests that $a^2+b^2$ and $2ab+1$ are also both primes; is this supposed to be a constraint here as well?

Comment: Thanks good point. I rewrote the question to be more explicit.

Comment: In 2012, I conjectured that any odd number greater than one can be written as $a+b$ with $a$ and $b$ positive integers such that both $a^2+b^2$ and $2ab+1$ are prime. See Conjecture 4.13(iv) of my preprint http://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.1588v27.pdf

Comment: As $\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{pq}\le\frac{p+q}2=\frac{(a+b)^2-1}2$, maybe we should test odd number $x\ge\sqrt{2\sqrt{n}+1}$ and write $x=a+b$ with $p=a^2+b^2$ and $q=2ab+1$ both prime (this can be done as conjectured by me in 2012) and then check whether $pq=n$.